# If there is not a directory, how can I disable the message? python

Tags: python

If for example I was using the following code to open an application:

```
import os
os.system("open /Applications/IAmAnApp.app")
```

But if there is no such application such as IAmAnApp, it will display this message:

```
The file /Users/Username/Desktop/Python/iamanapp does not exist.
```

I tried using try then except, but it's not an error, just a message.

How can I disable this message and just let the code continue?

Comment: use subprocess instead

Comment: Check to see if it exists first: http://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/535275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a message printed by `open` (whatever this command is), how about testing for file existence before?

```
os.system("test -f /Applications/IAmAnApp.app && open /Applications/IAmAnApp.app")
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I feel dumb I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.call(["open /Applications/IAmAnApp.app"])
except OSError:
    dosomething_else
```

Comment: Thank you! I would've used that except I was trying to teach my friend about the open command using import os. I should've been more clear about that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shell to redirect the output.

```
os.system('bash -c "open /Applications/IAmAnApp.app &> /dev/null"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy method: use `os.path.isdir` to detect the presence of the app. Here’s an example:

```
import os

app_path = os.path.join('/Applications', 'Safari.app')
if os.path.isdir(app_path):
    print 'installed!'
else:
    print 'not installed!'
```

Note that you have to use `isdir`, not `isfile`, because OS X `.app` bundles are really directories that get special treatment from the Finder. This also seems to work for symlinks, but I don’t know how it would work for aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module which is intended to replace `os.system`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['open', '/Applications/IAmAnApp.app'],
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```